# MongoDb null unique indexes

Tags: c#, mongodb

How can I create 2 indexes in MongoDB, (e.g., `ID` and `DateTime`) and set `ID` as a unique index, but if the identifier is null, set `DateTime` as a unique index?

Comment: indexes are not conditional. You either have one on a column or not.

Comment: thank you for your response,  if you have some solution to the issue I would be glad to hear

Comment: An ID column that can be null sounds odd.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take the [tour] of the site to understand how stackoverflow works and how to ask good  questions. Then come back and [edit] your question. Include the code of what you've tried as a [mcve], plus any error messages. Ask specific questions. Most people are happy to help, but don't want to do you work for you. Questions like "how do I do x?" that don't show any research effort on your end are likely to get ignored.

Comment: @Robert okay, thanks

Comment: Improved formatting.